# How can I persist Model values when passing serialized Model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a View which uses a ViewModel with the Next structure: Parent <- Children <- GrandChidlren. The ViewModel is a complex type, so in order to pass it to the Controller - I am serializing it to a Json string like this:

```
<input type="submit"
 value="Update Survey"
 class="btn btn-danger"
 formaction=@Url.Action("Save", 
 new
    {                                                                                        
       data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)
    }) 
/>
```

But doing this way - only the structure is persisted, but not it's values. That values from the Editors for the fields are not passed to the Controller, but instead are with initial values.

Comment: What is the point of passing back the original model. Its not really clear what you wanting to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am passing updated model to the controller in order to save it to the DB. Or this the wrong way to do that? Sorry if it sounds too basic - never had a chance to work with asp.mvc before.

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)` is serializing the original model (including its values), not what has been edited in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is true, but was not obvious for me. In this case - is there a way I can access to the current state of the model from the View?

Comment: You just post you form using a submit button. If you have generated you view correctly based on your model, then the model will be correctly bound in the POST method (you have not shown any of your code so we cannot tell if its correct)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is true, but because of the hierarchy structure of the Model - it does not attach the children and the grandchildren to the ViewModel, when passing it to the Controller (and taht was the initial reason, why I decided to serialize the model)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161617/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-egor-osaulenko).